# Return First Column Header of Instance of String

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a collection of speakers who have spoken various dates.

```
Date,1/2/2023,1/2/2022,1/2/2021,1/2/2020,1/2/2019,1/2/2018
                        
1st-Speaker,Jim,John,Fred,Sam,Scott,Riley
2nd-Speaker,Henry,Susan,John,Henry,Scott,Hugo
Lunch,Bob,Haley,Jim,Ed,Orin,Clark
3rd-Speaker,Simba,Riley,Sam,Scott,Ed,Hal
```

I would like to find the most recent (first, farthest left) date they have spoken. Using:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($B$3:$G$6=D13)*(COLUMN($B$3:$G$6))))-COLUMN($B$1)+1)
```

I can get the first date(last, farthest right) they spoke (D13 being the speaker I'm querying), but changing `MAX` to `MIN` doesn't return anything.

How do I update the equation to give the first instance instead of the last?

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,1,MIN(IF($B$3:$G$6=Z1,COLUMN($B$3:$G$6)-COLUMN($B$3)+1)))
```

Explanation:

- If data matches speaker, return the column number relative to the starting column B3

  ```
  IF($B$3:$H$6=Z1,COLUMN($B$3:$H$6)-COLUMN($B$3)+1)
  ```
- Find the minimum value in the resultant array

  ```
  MIN(...)
  ```
- Return the value from the first row (date) from the min

  ```
  INDEX($B$1:$H$1, 1, ...)
  ```

Adding `IFERROR(...,"")` handles if someone hasn't spoken (*I also had to format the cell to be a date specifically, otherwise it was a date serial*-or use `TEXT(..., "dd/mm/yyyy")`)

Answer (score 0):

If your original data looks like:

[image]

and you have Microsoft 365, you can use this single formula in some cell:

```
=LET(
    spkrs, SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL($B$3:$G$6))),
    dts, BYROW(
        spkrs,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            MAX(
                $B$1:$G$1 *
                    ISNUMBER(FIND(arr, $B$3:$G$6))
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(
        {"Speaker", "Most Recent Date"},
        HSTACK(spkrs, dts)
    )
)
```

and the results will `SPILL` showing the most recent date for all of the speakers:

[image]

***Note: In place of the hard-coded range references, you can create a `Table` and use structured references which will auto-adjust the range as you add (or remove) data***

If you name your table `Speaker` you could use a formula like below:

```
=LET(
    x, SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(DROP(Speaker, , 1)))),
    spkrs, FILTER(x, x <> ""),
    dts, BYROW(
        spkrs,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            MAX(
                DROP(Speaker[#Headers], , 1) *
                    ISNUMBER(
                        FIND(arr, DROP(Speaker, , 1))
                    )
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(
        {"Speaker", "Most Recent Date"},
        HSTACK(spkrs, dts)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula works in Excel and Google Sheets. It first builds a two row representation of the data and ultimately finds the MIN() date on columns filtered for a name. I initially tried MINIFS() to do what's now handled by FILTER() but I was getting an error:

```
=LET(crit, D13, 
dates,$B$1:$G$1,
namerow, TOROW($B$3:$G$6), 
daterow,HSTACK(dates,dates,dates,dates), 
tbl,VSTACK(daterow,namerow),
fltr,FILTER(tbl,INDEX(tbl,2)=crit),
MIN(INDEX(fltr,1)))
```